# How can I expose JMX of DATANODE in HDFS by using jmx_exporter

Tags: hdfs, jmx, jmx-exporter

I have tried to insert

```
export HDFS_DATANODE_OPTS="$HDFS_DATANODE_OPTS -javaagent:/usr/local/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.19.0.jar=hadoop1:30002:/usr/local/prometheus/jmx/prometheus_config.yml"
```

in `hadoop-env.sh`, where `prometheus_config.yml` is an empty file.
But 30002 is still closed, why?

I have ever tried to insert

```
if ! grep -q <<<"$HDFS_DATANODE_OPTS" jmx_prometheus_javaagent; then
export HDFS_DATANODE_OPTS="$HDFS_DATANODE_OPTS -javaagent:/usr/local/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.19.0.jar=hadoop1:30002:/usr/local/prometheus/jmx/prometheus_config.yml"
fi
```

but it is still not work!